# javascript parsing int values into int

Tags: javascript, casting, type-conversion, conditional-statements

I have an array of objects and there is the property `id` which may contains integers or strings. I'm using that property to compare, but now I'm guessing if it is more efficient to always convert that `id` in integer even if it is an integer or to ask if it is an string and then convert it. I mean this:

```
let myArray = [{id: 1, ...otherprops}, {id: 2, ...otherprops}, {id: '3', ...otherprops}, {id: '4', ...otherprops}];
```

Is this more efficient ...

```
for (let x of myArray) {
   if (parseInt(x.id, 10) === 3) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Or this code:

```
for (let x of myArray) {
   let id = -1;
   if (typeof x.id === 'string') {
      id = parseInt(x.id, 10);
   }
   if (id === 3) { ... }
}
```

Since the first code always convert I don't know if two conditions are better.

Comment: @Bian Goole -- the [tag:parsing] tag is not about conversion of strings to numeric types; please read about the intended uses of tags before adding them....

Comment: @DavidBowling I appreciate your comment, it was the way I found to a quick solution. I reading now what you've suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know, that you have just numbers or stringed numbers, then you could take an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) for conversion to a number, which does not change numbers.

```
var id = +x.id;
```

Comment: that's it, it solves the problem... I didn't know that... thanks